# SharePoint 2013 search result links not working

Tags: search

We just started having an issue recently in our SharePoint 2013 Enterprise site. When we search for something, it will find the item but clicking the link results in a "file not found" error. An example:

**Searched for Empower Park Map**

Result:
[image]

The URL for the resulting link is:
...empowernet/Documents/EmpowerParkMap.pdf#search=empower%20park%20map

The direct link for the only file on our site by that name is:
...empowernet/Documents/Empower%20Park%20Map%202017.pdf

I also checked and the Name and Title are the same (Empower Park Map 2017.pdf) for the actual file.

The search only returns one result and it does not appear to be the correct one, even though there is only one file on our site with that search value in its name. This is also not the only file it is doing this for.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked if there is a value in the Title property of the PDF document?

Comment: As I mentioned above, the Title and Name have the same value.

Comment: Did the problem just appeared? What buildversion are your farm running at?

Comment: I don't know exactly when it started, but we noticed it back in January. I have been trying to find a solution on my own first before posting in a forum. I'm not sure what buildversion we are running (I'll try to find out from one of our IT guys). We generally try to keep it updated monthly though.